# How to keep the same width of Bar-chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndroidChart draw the stick line. please look at the following image, I want to the two image bar-chart width is same, how can I do what?

[screenshot_one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0hxB.png)
[screenshot_two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpBSk.png)

Comment: i have experinced the same problem. for that i had to modify library little bit.

Comment: Can you tell me where you changed，THX

Answer (score 0):

As of this library version, you can control the bar width with the following method:

```
BarData barData = new BarData(...);
barData.setBarWidth(1f); // adjust according to your need
```